# I'll get a databae error when updating a entry using the channel polls field type

Tags: database, error, developer-log, devdemon

Recently I've installed the Channel Polls module of Devdemon on my development environment.
I addded the fieldtype to the channel and edited a existing entry, when I press submit the system will throw a database error.

[image: INSERT INTO <code>exp_developer_log</code> (<code>site_id</code>, <code>entry_id</code>, <code>channel_id</code>, <code>field_id</code>, <code>member_id</code>, <code>poll_status</code>, <code>allow_multiple</code>, <code>member_groups</code>, <code>result_order</code>, <code>show_results</code>, <code>chart_type</code>, <code>chart_width</code>, <code>chart_height</code>, <code>chart_bg</code>, <code>function</code>, <code>line</code>, <code>file</code>, <code>deprecated_since</code>, <code>use_instead</code>, <code>timestamp</code>) VALUES ('1', '4', '5', '68', 1, '1', '0', '1|5', 'answer_order', 'after_vote', 'google_pie_3d', '350', '300', 'FFFFFF', 'convert_human_date_to_gmt()', 478, 'C:\Projects\SP Haarlem\Website\Development\2.6.1\system\expressionengine\third_party\channel_polls\ft.channel_polls.php', '2.6', 'Localize::string_to_timestamp', 1370352409)]

> Unknown column 'site_id' in 'field list'
>
> INSERT INTO `exp_developer_log` (`site_id`, `entry_id`, `channel_id`, `field_id`, `member_id`, `poll_status`, `allow_multiple`, `member_groups`, `result_order`, `show_results`, `chart_type`, `chart_width`, `chart_height`, `chart_bg`, `function`, `line`, `file`, `deprecated_since`, `use_instead`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('1', '4', '5', '68', 1, '1', '0', '1|5', 'answer_order', 'after_vote', 'google_pie_3d', '350', '300', 'FFFFFF', 'convert_human_date_to_gmt()', 478, 'C:\Projects\Website\Development\2.6.1\system\expressionengine\third_party\channel_polls\ft.channel_polls.php', '2.6', 'Localize::string_to_timestamp', 1370352409)

When I lookup the table *exp_developer_log* I see a lot of fields but not the fields that a described in the query above.

Comment: In order to still be able to develop my website using channel polls I've disabled the line of code that triggers the logging method.

Library - Localize.php - Line 933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Channel Polls and ExpressionEngine 2.6.1. I have replied to your support ticket and we will get a new version out asap with support for 2.6.1.

Thanks!

Brad

Comment: Thanks! I have also created a bug report at Ellislab https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19468

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in the latest Channel Polls release.

Answer (score 0):

We have the latest version 2.7.4 together with EE 2.5.3 but get a similar error.
Any idea what this can be?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ee() in
>   /.../system/expressionengine/third_party/channel_polls/ft.channel_polls.php
>   on line 476